# Htaccess issue with a site that appears offline but if refreshed it works

Tags: internet-explorer, .htaccess, browser

When i click on a link to my page (from search engines for example) my page appears offline, but if I refresh the browser it works as normal. This happens about 1 out of 4 times i tried. Now, I have noticed this behaviour since I wrote the code for the .htaccess so I think this can be the problem but I am not that sure,,, Another thing, this happens only with IE in my test. I could not find enough information about this issue online, i hope someone here can explain where the problem can be.

Comment: I also found that some code was written like this:           $siteurl = mysite.com; and I changed into                   $siteurl = WWW.mysite.com;                                                     ...can be only that difference with the "www" the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you look inside apache2's access.log and error.log? 
You can enable [rewritelog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) directive to debug rewrites, if you have any.

Comment: hi, thank you. I also found that some code was written like this: $siteurl = http://mysite.com/;   and I changed into $siteurl = http://WWW.mysite.com/;   ...can be only that difference with the "www" the cause of the problem?